# Can I attach a piece of text to a transaction record?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

According to the docs for [`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) and the docs for [`eth_sendTransaction`](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Ethereum.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/eth_sendTransaction.html):

The transaction object can contain an optional `data` parameter which should be a `String` that consists of:

*either an ABI byte string containing the data of the function call on a contract, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction the initialisation code.*

I want to assign a string to `data` and have the string be stored along with the record of the transaction on the blockchain, so that I can retrieve that string when I retrieve the record of that transaction later.

```
const [testAccount] = await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
    
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)

if (!testAccount) {
  return
}

let transactionHash = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: testAccount,
  to: testAccount,
  value:  web3.utils.toWei('0.0003'), 
  data: web3.utils.utf8ToHex(JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 }))
})

let transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash)
let data = JSON.parse(web3.utils.hexToUtf8(transaction.data))
console.log(data.a) // should log 1
```

When I execute `sendTransaction` (using Metamask, while connected to the Ropsten network), I get the following error:

```
Error:  Error: TxGasUtil - Trying to call a function on a non-contract address
{
  "originalError": {
    "errorKey": "transactionErrorNoContract",
    "getCodeResponse": "0x"
  }
}
```

Apparently, you cannot assign any string to `data` and expect the string to be incorporated in the record of the transaction on the blockchain, out-of-the-box, simply by assigning a value to it. **Is this correct?**

**Question:** Do I need to write a custom smart-contract in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature/limitation specific to MetaMask. Possibly to protect their users who want to interact with a smart contract but are connected to a different network where the contract is not deployed.

However, it is technically possible to send a valid transaction with non-empty `data` field to a non-contract address. You just need to use  a different node provider to broadcast the transaction. Unfortunately the node provider in MetaMask is hardcoded so it's not possible using this wallet.

Example: [This transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe2310ac45711408a1a64cc00f24a6147cb54ac3f5b5b163b8b427b6de9ff0fd1) on the **Ropsten testnet** to the `0xdac1...` address that has the [USDT](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) token contract deployed on the mainnet, but is a non-contract address on the testnet. It is a valid transaction, successfully bought gas from the sender address to cover the transaction fees, mined in a block, just didn't execute any smart contract code (as there is no smart contract on the recipient address).

Comment: Could you suggest some other common node providers that would allow this ? It's a shame because MetaMask seems widely used and users are used to it by now I believe. Thanks!

Comment: And if I were to create a smart-contract just to be able to do this, would it work with MetaMask in that case ?

Comment: @SproutCoder Widely used are [Infura](https://infura.io/product/ethereum), [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/ethereum), and [Moralis](https://moralis.io/speedy-nodes/) for example. Mind that you'd need to know the sender's private key or let them sign the transaction outside of MetaMask (as MM doesn't allow just signing a transaction without broadcasting it; you can sign a message but that's a different thing) and then broadcast the signed transaction through any of these nodes... If you used a smart contract as a mediator, then yes - it would work with MetaMask.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to write a custom smart-contract in order to achieve this ?

You can also write a smart contract function in Solidity that receives data as a function argument, but does nothing on this. Thus, GoEthereum node stores this data as `calldata` of the transaction and it can be later retrieved.

I am pretty sure some cross-chain bridges operate in this manner. Transactions only write data as the part of calldata (cheaper than Solidity storage) and then other clients read it from there.